# Weather Reporting of wind direction

Tags: weather

General weather reporting for wind direction in Australian Standard the degrees in wind direction identifies where the wind is coming from.

Is it the same around the world?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is generally used that the broadcast wind is the magnetic heading for the direction the wind is coming from. This is because standard runway numbering is magnetic direction and pilots can easily determine the most appropriate runway given the wind.

Comment: I always thought it was because phrases such as "north wind" and "west wind" have always referred to winds *from* the north and west, respectively, and the most obvious convention is to report a "west wind" as 270.